# How do I read the date created info of a file from URL

Tags: bash, file, date, url, terminal

Is it possible for me to get the creation date of a file given a url without downloading the file?

lets say its http:///sever1.example.com/foo.bar. How do I get the date that foo bar was created on a bash terminal

Comment: You should look at [HTTP headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields). You can then ask a new question: How do I get the headers of an answer to a http request and how do I send the request from the console. Additionally I would not necessarily think of `foo.bar` as a file, rather a resource somewhere.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann i will add a solution with curl based on your comment thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `curl`, BASH can handle TCP connections:

```
$ exec 5<>/dev/tcp/google.com/80
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" >&5
$ head -5 <&5
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 13:29:30 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
$ exec 5>&-
```

Comment: how can I get a date for this https://en.wikipedia.org/static/apple-touch/wikipedia.png

Answer (score 0):

Inline with @MichaWiedenmann I see the only solution is to use a 3rd party binary like curl to help bash in the command

`curl -Is http://server1.example.com/foo.bar`

This would print information which can be manipulated with **grep** and **sed** to fit my purposes